# token illegal; PHP inside JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I use php in my JavaScript code to print a JavaScript line but I have an error. what am I doing wrong?

```
<?php  
    if (isset($_GET['dateSelected'])) {
        echo '$("#eliminarCitaBtn").attr("href", "index.php/agenda/eliminarCita/"+event.cita_id+"/?agendaId='.$_GET["agendaId"].'&dateSelected='.$_GET["dateSelected"].');';
    } else {
        echo "$('#eliminarCitaBtn').attr('href', 'index.php/agenda/eliminarCita/'+event.cita_id+'/?agendaId=".$_GET['agendaId'].");";
    }
?>
```

Comment: The error is token illegal

Comment: You should probably `urlencode()` at the very least but also verify the input for security reasons. That is easily injectable with malicious XXS script.

Comment: Also check you have enough `'`/`"` in the correct spots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are't closing the quotes at the end of either attr().

There `'");';` and there `"');";`

Comment: brother have reason had not closed the quotes of attr('') thanks